# How to allocate a gsl_vector on the stack?

Tags: memory, performance, c++, memory-management, gnu

I am using the GNU gsl library for linear algebra operations on vectors and matrices in C++ (vs2005). I am introducing this into old code, trying to keep the API of my class `Vector` intact.
Apart from a lot of functionality the `Vector` class holds the member

```
protected:
    gsl_vector *vec;
```

My default constructor calls:

```
inline Vector::Vector ()
{
    vec = gsl_vector_calloc(3);
}
```

This is terribly slow as `calloc`/`alloc` is an implementation of `new`. Is it possible in any way to allocate this on the stack instead?
My `Vector` is always of the same size, however the number of `Vectors` varies a lot while running the application.

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know anything about the gsl library, but if you have a known size why not just use an array (or `std::array` if you're in C++11 or later).

Comment: Unfortunately the gsl library only accepts `gsl_vector` type. The application is running winCE, so this is created using C++98.